# Achieve affect of sklearn's MultilabelBinarizer with dask dataframe map_partitions

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dask

I'm attempting to use sklearn's MultilabelBinarizer preprocessing function to take a 1-column df in which each cell is a list and return a categorical encoding

e.g.

```
[1,2]
[1]
[3,2]
[1]
```

becomes a dataframe like:

```
1 1 0
1 0 0
0 1 1   
1 0 0
```

It works with a normal pandas dataframe, but with a *dask* dataframe, it fails with NotImplementedError.

Does anyone know an alternative method to compute such an encoding with a dask dataframe in distributed manner?

Here is the working code:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
def binarize_data(df):

    # Binarize connectors
    mlb=MultiLabelBinarizer()
    tmp = df.iloc[:, 0]

    res=mlb.fit_transform(tmp)
    binarized_data = pd.DataFrame(res,
                                 columns=[tmp.name+"_" +
                                          c for c in mlb.classes_],
                                 index=tmp.index, dtype='int')

    return binarized_data
binarize_data(pd.DataFrame(dict(foo=pd.Series([["1","2"], ["1"], ["3", "2"], ["1"]]))))
```

and here is the failing dask code:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
def binarize_data(df):

    # Binarize connectors
    mlb=MultiLabelBinarizer()
    tmp = df.iloc[:, 0]

    res=mlb.fit_transform(tmp)
    binarized_data = pd.DataFrame(res,
                                 columns=[tmp.name+"_" +
                                          c for c in mlb.classes_],
                                 index=tmp.index, dtype='int')

    return binarized_data
binarize_data(dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(dict(foo=pd.Series([["1","2"], ["1"], ["3", "2"], ["1"]]))), npartitions=10))
```

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?